# TYPO3 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException

Tags: symfony, typo3

[image]

This is the error message I got!

What does it mean, no such service exists?

Here the code of the `SpeciesSelectController`:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use \HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller;

/**
 * SpeciesSelectController
 */
class SpeciesSelectController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * SpeciesSelectRepository
     * 
     * @var \HGA\Hgaplantdb\Domain\Repository\SpeciesSelectRepository
     */
    protected $speciesSelectRepository = null;

    /**
     * @param \HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller\Domain\Repository\SpeciesSelectRepository $speciesSelectRepository
     */
    public function injectSpeciesSelectRepository(\HGA\Hgaplantdb\Domain\Repository\SpeciesSelectRepository $speciesSelectRepository)
    {
        $this->speciesSelectRepository = $speciesSelectRepository;
    }
```

And here the `Services.yaml` file:

```
# Configuration/Services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  HGA\Hgaplantdb\:
    resource: '..\Classes\*'
    exclude: '..\Classes\Domain\Model\*'

  HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller\SpeciesSelectController:
    public: true

  HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller\PlantController:
    public: true
```

Also after asking Google, I have currently no idea, what is wrong!

Comment: Have you flushed the cache via Admin Tools > Maintenance after adding the inject method to the controller?

Comment: The error message comes up after trying to install the extension and than the backend was not working anymore. Therefore I deleted `cache dir` complete by hand. Now the extension is installed and the backend working again. But now a got a now error, if I try to open the page for this extension. The system cannot find a controller. So I have to look for the error. But anyway thanks for your help, it brough me a step further.

Comment: @Chris, I have again deleted the extension and tried to instll them again. The same problem appears. So there is something not correct. Any idea what the error message with service means?

Answer (score 1):

Due to another problem with a different extension, I was thinking, that for windows I had to use `\` instead of `/` in the `Service.yaml` file. But this was a mistake! After changing it back to

```
HGA\Hgaplantdb\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'
    exclude: '../Classes/Domain/Mode/*'
```

it was working fine. Here the complete corrected file:

```
# Configuration/Services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  HGA\Hgaplantdb\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'
    exclude: '../Classes/Domain/Mode/*'

  HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller\SpeciesSelectController:
    public: true

  HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller\PlantController:
    public: true
```